# Indexing and finding a key value in a named tuple

Tags: list, python-3.4, namedtuple

I have a named tuple with values [x,y].
Both fields will hold strings.
My problem is ,I want to match the contents of the 'x' field and access the 'y' field of that index.

```
name_array_tuple_list
```

is the name of the list which holds the named tuples.

So far I have got this

```
print([x[0] for x in name_array_tuple_list].index('SNVT'))
```

Which prints the index of the matched value.
My question is how to access the y value of lets say the index 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close.  Try this:

```
 print([point.y for point in name_array_tuple_list if point.x == 'SNVT'])
```

Interpret the code as follows:

- print
- a list of
- *y* field contents
- for every named tuple in a list
- but only if the named tuple's *x* field matches `SVNT`